# How to bold some php string

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to make a certain string bold in a text. I went through my php book and looked online, but no solutions helped with my problem. The variable `$mapname` and `$post_title` change because they're in a while loop which is working fine for replacing certain characters, like this one for example:

```
$data_p = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE verified='yes' ORDER BY (posvotes - negvotes) DESC $max"; 
$exec_p = $mysqli->query($data_p);
while($row = $exec_p->fetch_object())
{ 
$post_id = $row->post_id;
$maps = "SELECT name FROM maps WHERE id='$post_id'";
$getmaps = $mysqli->query($maps);
$mapname = $getmaps->fetch_object();
$post_title = preg_replace('/(Free )/',"<b>\\0</b>", $post_title);
```

but when I try to replace a string

```
$post_title = str_replace($mapname,'<b>'.$mapname.'</b>', $post_title);
```

I don't get any output at all. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? When I disable the `str_replace` and just var_dump the variables, I always get the correct variables.
I browsed the web for solutions and the `str_replace` function should be working according to the manuals.

Comment: `$mapname` is an object, not a string...

Comment: Are you actually echoing the results?

Comment: Also, you should almost certainly be using `<strong>...</strong>`, not `<b>`. While `<b>` is a valid tag in HTML5 (it is deprecated in HTML4), it is not ordinary bolded text—almost always, you mean "strong emphasis" and as such should use `<strong>`.

Comment: ^^even better css `font-weight:bold`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you provided, `$mapname` is an object, NOT a string. You need to try something like this: `$post_title = str_replace($mapname->name,'<b>'.$mapname->name.'</b>',$post_title);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like

```
$post_title = str_replace($mapname->columnName,'<b>'.$mapname->columnName.'</b>', $post_title);
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
$mapname = $getmaps->mysqli_fetch_array();
```

and then try with your code...